# Dynamically populate the menu when a new category is created

Tags: menus

I was asked to make a dynamic menu with sub-items. This is the idea:

```
$categories = array{
‘cars’,
‘boats’,
‘airplanes’
};
```

| Home | About us | **Categories** |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | **Cars** |
|  |  | **Boats** |
|  |  | **Airplanes** |

On the Categories session, I’ll place an array dynamically populated with all categories.
And… The most important part… Every time a new category is added by the user, a
new sub-item must be added automatically.

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

yes, of course it is possible to do.
Here is the code to get all the categories on a page load, this code is prepared to go until the 3rd category generation.

```php
$cats = get_categories( array('taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'hide_empty' => true) );
foreach ($cats as $key => $cat):
    if ($cat->parent == 0):
        echo $cat->name;
        foreach ($cats as $key => $cat2):
            if ($cat2->parent == $cat->term_id):
                echo $cat2->name;
                foreach ($cats as $key => $cat3):
                    if ($cat3->parent == $cat2->term_id):
                        echo $cat3->name;
                    endif;
                endforeach;
            endif;
        endforeach;
    endif;
endforeach;
```